# foreach cannot find `i` used in foreach(i=1:N)

Tags: r, foreach

I'm having some troubles with the variables inside a `foreach`. I load the cluster and set up a couple of vectors:

```
library(doParallel)
ncores <- detectCores() - 2
cl <- makeCluster(ncores, outfile="", port=11439)
registerDoParallel(cl)    

results <- rep(NA,10)
values <- 20:30
```

Then, it does not work:

```
# Error: object 'i' not found
foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% 
  results[i] <- i

stopCluster(cl)
```

While this does:

```
# ok 
foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% 
  values[i]

stopCluster(cl)
```

How come it finds `i` when it is used inside a `[i]` in the left hand side, but it does not find it when used in the right hand side?

Comment: Have you tried adding curly brackets? ```foreach (...) %dopar% {...} ```

Comment: oh my god! It works, indeed! what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment:

try it with curly braces.

```
foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% {
  results[i] <- i
}
```

Not just with this example, I experienced it is better to use curly braces in R. Many Problems can be avoided by using them. And apparently there are some more advantages of these little helpers, as you may see while browsing through the Internets (e.g. [see here](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/two-surpising-things-about-r/)).